# Order of non-blocking writes in Java

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio, channel

Java's NIO provides lots of useful features. One of them is the possibility of non blocking write operations on channels. This means that the write method will not block until the write is done.

But is it still provided that all writes are written in the same order as the writes are called even though the methods don't block?

Comment: If you think you have to ask this question you already have a bigger design problem. You shouldn't be writing to a socket from multiple threads in the first place, and if you're using non-blocking I/O you don't have any need for multiple threads in the first place. Some architectural confusion here.

Comment: I'm not using multiple threads. I'm just calling the write method several times in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you're considering is unlikely, considering the fact that the NIO api does not allow a program to write to the same channel, within the same thread, before a previous write completes. A [WritePendingException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/WritePendingException.html) is thrown. From the docs:

> Unchecked exception thrown when an attempt is made to write to an asynchronous socket channel and a previous write has not completed.

The way the Async API is built, the most you can do is either attempt to write from a different thread, or wait until the first write is complete before initiating another

Comment: Is it possible to make reads non blocking and writes blocking for a channel?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock - Not the same channel, no. There are asynchronous channels for non-blocking I/O and plain [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) for blocking I/O